# Eclipse = What happens if a class is included in project and library

Tags: java, eclipse

What happens if a class (x.java) file exists both in the current project and in the library it uses.
Which one will it take?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It *should* be the one first loaded by the order defined in Project Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export.

Answer (score 1):

The projects binaries should come first.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path");
```

prints the current classpath to the console - in my case, the projects bin folder is the first entry, followed by the projects libraries.

---

*Note* - with the above statement I can confirm [zeropages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188053/eclipse-what-happens-if-a-class-is-included-in-project-and-library/6188121#6188121) answer. Changing the projects properties ("Order and export") changes the classpath which can be verified through the above statement.